# Difficulty with COUNT in mySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I have a database with game scores of a squash tournament which looks like follows:

**MatchResult**

[image]

**GameResult**

[image]

From this you can gather that Team A has beaten Team B by the following results:

Batman has beaten Superman 3-0: 11-1, 11-2, 11-3

Mufasa has beaten Scar 3-0: 11-1, 11-1, 11-1

I can get the points and matches won/lost by each team with selects like these

**Points Won**

```
(Select((SELECT IFNULL((SELECT SUM(GRA.PlayerAPoints)
    FROM GameResult GRA
    JOIN MatchResult mA ON GRA.MatchResultId = mA.Id
    WHERE mA.PlayerATeamId = team.Id),0))
+    
(SELECT IFNULL((SELECT SUM(GRB.PlayerBPoints)
    FROM GameResult GRB
    JOIN MatchResult mB ON GRB.MatchResultId = mB.Id
    WHERE mB.PlayerBTeamId = team.Id),0)))) AS 'PointsWonA'
```

**GamesWon**

```
(Select(SELECT IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*)
                        FROM GameResult GRA
                        JOIN MatchResult mA ON GRA.MatchResultId = mA.Id
                        Where GRA.PlayerAPoints > GRA.PlayerBPoints
                        AND mA.PlayerATeamId = team.Id)
                    ,0)
        )
        +
        (SELECT IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                FROM GameResult GRB
                                JOIN MatchResult mB ON GRB.MatchResultId = mB.Id
                                Where GRB.PlayerBPoints > GRB.PlayerAPoints
                                AND mB.PlayerBTeamId = team.Id)
                            ,0)
                )       
) AS 'GamesWonA'
```

However, I am struggling with how to get the count of matches won by a team per fixture. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably want to count those games where 'givenTeam' is teamA AND teamA score > teamB score OR givenTeam is teamB AND teamB > teamA. Sorry for this clunky pseudocode, but i'm at work and i can't spare much time on SO :P. Hope this is good enough, if not when i get home i prepare a better answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. In the example above, I would like to get back that TeamA has won 2 matches, and that TeamB have won zero matches for that particular fixture